# query_posts orderby postmeta

Tags: query-posts, post-meta

I'm trying to retrieve a custom post type and order it by a custom date stored in postmeta.

The custom date is a unix timestamp. 
The meta_query works correctly - it only retrieves posts with a custom date in the future.

But the orderby does not work - the order is still based on the post_date.

What am I missing?

```
   $today = date("m/d/Y");
   $today = strtotime( $today ); 

    query_posts( array(
        'post_type'      => 'custom_cpt',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key'   => 'custom_date',
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,

        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'custom_date',
                'value'     => $today,
                'compare'   => '>',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: Solved - forgot to deactivate another plugin that was using the pre_get_posts hook - argh!

Answer (score 1):

For numeric data, the `orderby` key should have value as `meta_value_num`. Use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) and change

`'orderby'    => 'meta_value'`

to

`'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num'`

Comment: Tried using WP_Query but the order is still using post_date. Also tried using 'meta_value_num' in query_posts.

Comment: Also tried using post__in, but still ordered by post_date.

Comment: Solved - the problem was being dumb, see above. Thanks for trying to help.